# Scala - diff two list of case classes by subset of fields

Tags: scala, collections

Given two lists of case classes

```
case class Entity(field1: String, field2: String, field3: String)
val a: Seq[Entity] = ...
val b: Seq[Entity] = ...
```

How to find all entities in a that's not in b, based on only field1 and field2, ignoring field3?

I've considered overriding the equals() function for the case class, also the neat trick of case class ()(ignored fields goes here) approach, but there will need to be multiple combinations of these fields needed for different use cases, e.g. diff using field1 + field2, then using field 1 + field 3, etc...

Comment: I wouldn't override equals, because that is not intuitive. If you create a Set of Entities (E(a, b, c), E(a, b, d)) and only one  of them is added, because the second one is considered equal...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ints, instead of String, for easy testing:

```
def similar (e: Entity, f: Entity) = { e.field1 == f.field1 && e.field2 == f.field2 }

scala> a
res60: Seq[Entity] = List(Entity(1,2,3), Entity(1,3,4), Entity(4,6,8), Entity(3,4,5))

scala> b
res61: Seq[Entity] = List(Entity(1,3,5), Entity(4,6,8), Entity(4,9,25))

scala> a.filter (aa => {! b.exists {bb => similar (aa, bb)} })
res62: Seq[Entity] = List(Entity(1,2,3), Entity(3,4,5))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  val bad = b.iterator.map { x => x.field1 -> x.field2 }.toSet
  val filtered = a.filterNot { x => bad(x.field1 -> x.field2) }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter `a` with specific condition using `!b.exists()`:

```
case class Entity(field1: String, field2: String, field3: String)
val a = Seq(Entity("1", "p", "x"), Entity("2", "q", "y"), Entity("3", "r", "z"))
val b = Seq(Entity("1", "p", "x"), Entity("2", "q", "x"), Entity("3", "s", "z"))

a.filter( elA => 
  !b.exists(elB => elB.field1 == elA.field1 && elB.field2 == elA.field2)
)
// res1: Seq[Entity] = List(Entity(3,r,z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an entity mapping class that is only interested in fields you want to do the comparison on:

```
class EntityMap1_2( e: Entity ) {
  override def equals( o: Any ): Boolean = ???
  override def hashCode: Int = ???
}
```

It defines `equals` and `hashCode` only in terms of fields 1 and 2. Then you can populate respective sets and find the differences.

Similarly with other combinations of fields.